# Debian 9: What powered off my system?

Tags: debian, shutdown, unexpected-shutdown

For a day or so I've been trying to figure out what is powering off my system.  It's Debian 9 running on a Beaglebone Black, and 5 minutes after power up (give or take a few seconds) it powers itself off.  Some piece of software asks it to, and I can't find out what.

I've renamed /sbin/poweroff and /sbin/shutdown, they're gone, and it still shuts down.

I stopped all my apps/services.  Virtually nothing is running.  There's nothing in crontab.

I captured a dbus trace.  I'm not good at reading these, but here's the initial record:

> signal time=1645551940.832468 sender=:1.1 -> destination=(null
> destination) serial=32 path=/org/freedesktop/login1;
> interface=org.freedesktop.login1.Manager; member=PrepareForShutdown
> boolean true

Does this tell me anything?  Help!!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out /var/log/auth.log told me the answer.

```
Feb 22 12:15:27 as9004s systemd-logind[324]: Power key pressed.
Feb 22 12:15:27 as9004s systemd-logind[324]: Powering Off...
Feb 22 12:15:27 as9004s systemd-logind[324]: System is powering down.
```

Embedded system watchdog.  Beaglebone Black doesn't bring "reset" to the connectors, so it uses the power button signal to cycle power.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly there was an issue with a specific kernel version which after a shutdown command starts to boot again, I know it is not the same as your case, but can be a option.

Solution: Try updating the kernel